# Chromebook R11 Ubuntu 18.04 - No Sound (Please help)

Tags: 18.04

I recently completely installed Ubuntu 18.04 on my Chromebook R11 (CB5-132-C67Q) Everything about Ubuntu is awesome, other than the fact that no audio will play. I can't figure out any fix for this and now I am desperate for help. Iv'e looked everywhere and I cant find a solution.